# Arch linux: i3wm set lock time out (xss-lock i3lock)

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, i3, screen-lock, lock

I use arch with i3wm. I have enabled i3lock in my `.config/i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock
```

Problem is my computer locks like every 10 minutes. How can I set two hours lock timeout ?

This is my `xset q` output:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc,/usr/share/fonts/TTF,/usr/share/fonts/OTF,/usr/share/fonts/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/75dpi,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Comment: Is this triggered by [DPMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling)?

Comment: @stefan0xC I do not know. I to disable it. I let you know if its works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-dpms.conf` which contains:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "StandbyTime" "90"
    Option "SuspendTime" "90"
    Option "OffTime" "90"
    Option "BlankTime" "90"
EndSection
```

90 stands for 90 minutes

Answer (score 4):

A way of achieving it is by setting the screen timeout with xset.

```
xset dpms 0 0 300
```

**300** is equal to five minutes.
**7200** for two hours.

You can add the following to the auto start section on i3 config file in order to set the screen time to turn-off and trigger i3lock when it happens.

For five minutes of inactivity, turn off the screen and lock:

```
exec_always --no-startup-id xset dpms 0 0 300 &
exec_always --no-startup-id xss-lock -- i3lock -n -i background_image.png &
```

If you want to suspend your computer, add the corresponding parameters.

Note: `xss-lock` will also be triggered when your computer hibernates or suspends.